# Finding a grammar for given language

Tags: discrete-mathematics, computer-science, formal-languages, context-free-grammar

So for this problem we are given a language and we have to find the grammar for that set. I am confused and what the constructors should be.

The language in this problem is: $\{bb, bab, baab, baaab,...\}$ = $\{ba^nb | n \in \mathbb{N} \}$

For some, I know that one of the constructors involves the empty string, like $S \rightarrow \Lambda$, but that is usually when the empty string is included in the language (at least in the examples the professor showed us). So like $\{ \Lambda, bb, bab,...\}$. I looked in the back of the book and some of the other problems didn't have an empty string as one of their constructors.

I was thinking it's something like:

$S \rightarrow \Lambda$ | $bSb$ | $aS$

So that: $S => bSb => b\Lambda b => bb$ or $S => bSb => baSb => baaSb => baa\Lambda b => baab$

This gives me the language I am looking for somewhat, but what if $S => \Lambda$ right from the start? Then that messes me up since $\Lambda$ is not included in the language. Any idea on how to fix this?

Comment: It might be best to add another variable $C$.  Then you can do $S\to bCb$.  Then you can have $C\to \Lambda$ and $C\to aC$.

Answer (score 1):

Your suggested grammar has an additional problem besides generating the empty string: it generates $bbbb,bbbbbb,bbabb$, and infinitely many other words that you don’t want.

Note that the language is regular: it corresponds to the regular expression $ba^*b$. Thus, we should be able to come up with a regular grammar for it. Clearly the first terminal symbol that this grammar generates should be a $b$, and after that we want to be able to generate an arbitrary string of $a$s. That suggests a production $S\to bA$, where the non-terminal $A$ will be capable of generating a string of $a$s followed by a single $b$. Clearly we need $A\to b$ in order to be able to end a string correctly. The grammar needs just one more production in order to generate the right language; can you see what it is?

Comment: Yes! I see what I did wrong. I forgot that you can have different letters and different productions. For instance, I tried to have all my productions in S and looking back on it I see that it does create an infinite number of words that I do not want. I needed to split it up to where S was bCb and then have another variable C that was the empty string or aC. Harder to show in the comments since I don't know if LaTex can be used here.

Comment: @DietDrPepsi: Yes, you can use it in comments exactly the same way that you do in questions and answers.

Answer (score 0):

$S \mapsto bAb$

$A \mapsto aA | \Lambda$

This pretty much simplifies the process.

Comment: I've edited your question using MathJax, our maths renderer. Check the source (by clicking [edit]) to see how it works. For further information about writing maths at this site see e.g. [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/), [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/70559/155238), [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1773/) and [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/editing-help#latexhelp/notation).

Comment: Hey, how come everybody around seem to know latex? I am very much a noob to it.

Comment: It's an acquired skill, but one that is required for being a professional mathematician. LaTeX is the communication mechanism of choice for maths, and thus very prevalent on this site. The links I gave you will give you a nice introduction. And if you try using it, people are very willing to edit your contributions to also use it. This also gives you the chance to look at the source of the edited post and learn from that. This way, we all get a little better at LaTeX every day :).